# Numpy tile documentation

Tags: numpy

Can anybody please explain this numpy code:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0, 1, 2])
np.tile(a, (2,1,2))
```

The output for this is:

```
array([[[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]],
       [[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]]])
```

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html This is from where I copied the code.

Comment: What's the `shape` of the output?  It looks, to me, a (2,1,6).  `a` is (3,).  Reshape that to (1,1,3) as described in the docs.  Multiply by (2,1,2).

Answer (score 0):

welcome to Stack Overflow.

The function `tile` from numpy will tile (or copy multiple times if you will) a given array (first parameter) along the specified dimensions (second parameter).

Let me just add comments to point our what is going on in the documentation.

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0, 1, 2])  # array a has shape (3,)
# the following line tiles twice the array a along dimension 0, outputting shape (6,)
np.tile(a, (2))  # outputs [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
```

The documentation states that

> If A.ndim < d, A is promoted to be d-dimensional by prepending new
>   axes. So a shape (3,) array is promoted to (1, 3) for 2-D replication,
>   or shape (1, 1, 3) for 3-D replication. If this is not the desired
>   behavior, promote A to d-dimensions manually before calling this
>   function.

This means that if you call `np.tile(a, (2,2))`, the function will (1) prepend an axis of size 1 to `a` (because `a.ndim = 1` and `d = len((2,2)) = 2`) and (2) tile this array twice along axes 0 and 1, hence outputting an array of shape `(2*1, 2*3) = (2, 6)`.

To come back to your question, when calling `np.tile(a, (2, 1, 2))`, what happens is that the function prepends axes to `a` giving shape `(1, 1, 3)` and then tiles this augmented array as `(2*1, 1*1, 2*3) = (2, 1, 6)`, and if you, indeed, tile the array `[0, 1, 2]` this way, you do end up with the array `[[[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]][[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]]]`.

I hope it's helping ?